# Book Recommendation for Measure Theory in n-Space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, book-recommendation

What's a standard book on multidimensional measure theory? 
I'm aware of some books on functions of several variables, but they do not discuss measure theory or Lebesgue integration in space.

Thanks.

Comment: For a treatment based on abstract measure spaces, see *Real and Complex Analysis* by Rudin. For a more concrete approach, see Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis*.

Comment: Thanks. One thing I have against Rudin's blue book, there's no single graph illustrating the abstract concepts. I'm not sure about this book though.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't read it, but [*Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Space*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0763717088) by Frank Jones seems to fit the bill.